# Ways to Keep Stored Data after Page Reload

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if i want to save data before reloading ( on beforeUnload event )i have a model for the controller ; when refresh, the model is lost. I thought of cache or session ( i need to keep local data after reload)   can you please help ?

Comment: Cookies/Sessions would be good as long as it's not 2938 pages of information.

Comment: Take a look at the [Web Storage Overview](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/#comparison) and choose an API that is appropriate for your project and target platforms.